# Julia MethodError: no method matching take!(::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}})

Tags: julia

Julia 0.5 on Juliabox

Why does the below function definition yield the following error:

```
Julia MethodError: no method matching take!(::Base.AbstractIOBuffer{Array{UInt8,1}} )

function CoinTrials(x,y; numtrials=100000, numcoins=5 )
    Yes=[]
    No=[]
    for trial in 1:numtrials
        trialresults=[]
        for coin in 1:numcoins
            result = rand(1,2)
            push(vec,trialresults)
        end 
        if len(filter(x->x==1,trialresults)) >=3
            Yes+=1

        else
            No+=1
        end 
    end
    @printf(Yes,No)
end
```

Comment: This code is riddled with errors, julia 0.5 does not even come close to compiling it. What is vec? printf has to have string literal as its first arg. Please correct the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function CoinTrials(x,y; numtrials=100000, numcoins=5 )
```

...you don't seem to use `x` or `y`, so I'm not sure why they're here.

```
    Yes=[]
    No=[]
```

...since you later add 1, why not make these integer counters?

```
    for trial in 1:numtrials
        trialresults=[]
        for coin in 1:numcoins
            result = rand(1,2)
```

...this produces an array of two random Float64's between 0 and 1. Do you want an array or a single number?

```
            push(vec,trialresults)
```

...there's no `push` function. There is a `push!` function. Do you want `push!(trialresults, result)` to add the latest trial to the list of trial results?

```
        end 
        if len(filter(x->x==1,trialresults)) >=3
```

...there's no `len` function. There is a `length` function. This won't find Float64s in `trialresults` though.

```
            Yes+=1    
        else
            No+=1
        end 
    end
    @printf(Yes,No)
```

...you want a format string here: `@printf "%d %d" Yes No`

```
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your more than charitable reply.

This was a terrible attempt at writing this function done in the wee hours of the morning. 

I've corrected it, ran on my own system and am receiving a new error. Juliabox threw an error for anything I ran on it, even 1+1.